# How to Generate seperate access token for ldap users that loaded in wso2 API manager for getting apis?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 API manager 1.9.1 . I have loaded my local ldap in this . I have created some apis and subscribed in API store. Now i want to give authentication to these apis . I know generating application based token . I don't want this . I want to generate separate access token for each users to access the apis   . I have tried with grant_type password option and given user name and password from ldap users .

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Authorization: Basic <based64 key>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

Follwoing error shows

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant
is invalid."}
```

Please help

Comment: Do you have anything to share with us from log file?

Comment: It is better if you can provide the relevant log  to troubleshoot the issue. relevant log is in wso2carbon.log file which is located in <APIM_HOME>/repository/logs folder.